# Is Wikipedia's example on FOLLOW() sets in LR(1) parsing wrong?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, lr-grammar

I can't tell if I'm misunderstanding what's going on, or if Wikipedia's explanation is incorrect.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser#FIRST_and_FOLLOW_sets):

> `FOLLOW(k,B)` of an item set `k` and an nonterminal `B` is the union of the follow sets of all items in `K` where `'•'` is followed by `B`.

Their example grammar looks like this:

```
S → E
E → T
E → ( E )
T → n
T → + T
T → T + n
```

where they found the LR(0) item set 0 to be:

```
[S → • E]
[E → • T]
[E → • ( E )]
[T → • n]
[T → • + T]
[T → • T + n]
```

That means, then, that *`FOLLOW(0,T)` is the union of the follow sets of all items in item set 0 where '•' is followed by `T`.*

Applying their logic, we get that *"items in item set 0 where '•' is followed by `T`"* are in fact these two items:

- `[E → • T]`
- `[T → • T + n]`

However, this is where I get stuck:
The follow set of the second one includes the symbol `)`, because the item `[E → • ( E )]` can produce `[E → • ( T )]`, which means a `)` must be in the follow set.

However, Wikipedia says that `FOLLOW(0,T) = { $, '+' }`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the description of "Warshall's Closure Algorithm" in this book

[Bornat : Understanding and Writing Compilers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Writing-Compilers-Do---Yourself/dp/0333217322/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356010204&sr=8-1)

to be helpful here. (Overall I found that book more readable and practically useful than the more famous books on compiler design!)

There may be other good descriptions of the algorithm around.

EDIT : I am rusty but I believe Wikipedia article is right in this respect :

Remember this is `Follow(0,T)`.
Now you are clearly right that ')' can follow T in some circumstances.

However, not from a starting point of 0 ... that would mean an expression of the form `n)` or `n+n)` or `n+n+n)` which, written out explicitly like this, are obvious syntax errors.

(Making these things explicit instead of burying them in mathematical notation is what I *really* liked about that book!)